# Facturacion electronica uso de CFDI 3.3 problema con el UUID

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Quiero saber a que se iguala el `UUID`, ya que al dejarlo solo en *comillas("")* me dice que no puede quedar nulo. Lo estoy intentando poner de la siguiente manera:

```
cfdi.CfdiRelacionados = new ComprobanteCfdiRelacionados();
cfdi.CfdiRelacionados.CfdiRelacionado = new ComprobanteCfdiRelacionadosCfdiRelacionado[1];
cfdi.CfdiRelacionados.CfdiRelacionado[0].UUID = ? ;
```

Comment: ¿Qué tal con un `string.Empty`? Aunque por lo que veo, significa que el servicio del SAT requiere un UUID por fuerza.

Comment: El UUID relacionado se refiere por ejemplo al UUID de cada uno de los pagos de una factura, si se pagó de contado o si la factura no está pagada no lleva CFDI relacionados, has intentado omitir la asignación de valor a cfdi.CfdiRelacionados ?

Answer (score 1):

Es **forzoso** que lleve un UUID. La información que proporciona @AlejandroMedina es erronea, debido a que en esa sección no se está utilizando para referirse a los documentos que se han pagado, para eso está el comprobante de pagos.

Ahora bien, el caso mas simple que puedo mencionarte es cuando generas una nota de crédito (tipo = egreso) sobre una factura (tipo = ingreso), en ese supuesto, la nota de crédito debe especificar el UUID de la factura sobre la cual se le aplicará el efecto contable.

Comment: ¿Es eso un comentario o un intento de respuesta? Parece más lo primero que lo segundo

Comment: @JuanSimon mi comentario no es preciso y aclaro, el UUID efectivamente es forzoso cuando existe el elemento CfdiRelacionado, sin embargo si no tiene UUID que relacionar puede dejar nulo desde el elemento CfdiRelacionados (con s al final y que es padre de CfdiRelacionado sin s), para mejor entendimiento consultar la pagina 12 del documento del Anexo 20 para CFDI 3.3 del SAT http://www.sat.gob.mx/informacion_fiscal/factura_electronica/Documents/cfdv33.pdf

Comment: Otro documento util es la guía de llenado de CFDI 3,3:  http://www.sat.gob.mx/informacion_fiscal/factura_electronica/Documents/Gu%C3%ADaAnexo20.pdf

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro esa es su opinión. Pero sí, era la respuesta.

Comment: @AlejandroMedina tienes razón. La mejor referencia es la documentación del SAT. Sin embargo, reitero, el campo es obligatorio, en la liga que compartiste del documento del SAT indica la descripción del campo UUID y las caracteristicas del campo.

Comment: Reitero mi respuesta. **El UUID es forzoso**. No puede dejarse como cadena vacía o tener un valor distinto a la estructura de un UUID. Si al momento de serializar el objeto esto ocurre, cuando realices una petición para obtener el TFD, el PAC te dará una respuesta de estructura inválida en tu comprobante.

Comment: @JuanSimon lo comentaba porque esta pregunta había sido marcada para eliminación por los usuarios de la comunidad por no estar muy clara y/o considerarse de baja calidad. Entonces, ¿la solución es que el usuario utilice el UUID de la factura? ¿cómo se haría eso?

Comment: Partamos de que todo comprobante (CFDI) cuenta con un identificador único (UUID) al momento de ser certificado por un proveedor de certificación (PAC). 

Cuando uno emite una factura (o CFDI de tipo ingreso) por un monto, digamos 116 MXN, significa que el emisor recibió un ingreso de 100 (costo del producto/servicio) + 16 (impuesto). Ahora bien, es muy común que por temas de devoluciones del producto o cancelación de la factura se emita una nota de crédito (o CFDI de tipo egreso) por la misma cantidad (116 MXN) indicando que "contablemente" ya no cuentan con ese ingreso.

Comment: Significa que, el comprobante de egreso debe incluir en su detalle con qué otro comprobante está relacionado y cual es el tipo de relación. 

Habiendo dicho lo anterior, el campo UUID (en la estructura que indicaron en la pregunta) sirve para especificar el identificador del comprobante con el que se está relacionando, y de acuerdo al ejemplo que dí, la nota de crédito debe proveer el UUID de la factura que emitió en un inicio.

Aunque "tecnológicamente" es posible proveer una cadena vacía, una vez que se serialice esa clase a un XML el atributo quedará como `UUID=""` y eso de nada servirá

Comment: ¿Porqué no servirá? Porque el PAC está obligado a realizar ciertas validaciones antes de otorgar el TFD, y una de ellas es que verifique que los atributos requeridos no sean cadenas vacías. De antemano una disculpa por todo el discurso, pero creo que es importante que se aclaren todos los detalles. Y en mi mera opinión, la pregunta es válida, pero requiere conocimiento muy específico del negocio de la facturación electrónica en México.